# How do I set the layout constr to allow UITextview to fill the space between the UIImage and UIButton?

Tags: xamarin.ios, autolayout, storyboard

As per image below, how do I prevent the UITextView to overflow underneath the UIButton? There's a general leading and trailing space of 8 and the UITextView is set to word wrap and lines = 0. 
Content hugging prio on the UIButton is 751 which makes it restrict it's size to the entered text and not take up half of the space with the UITextField. I've set content insets on the UIButton to have some internal padding to the button text.

I want the button to resize correctly to its internal text, which may vary in length with translations, and then the text view to fill up the remaining width, but row break if it doesn't fit.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Set the right side of UITextView with a fixed padding to the left side of the button.

Comment: Yes, doesn't work. Perhaps hard to see in the image but it's there  it works fine until the text is too long then it gives warnings in the iOS designer and overflows in runtime.

Comment: You have **red** indications that your constraints are not setup correctly to begin with. Expand all the elements in the Document Outline pane (so every constraint is visible) and post a screen-cap of that.

Comment: If I reduce the text in the designer I loose them (see added image). Also posted the warnings. Pressing "add missing constraints" does nothing.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an editable `UITextView`? Or editable `UITextField`? Or a non-editable `UILabel`?

Comment: In this case it's a label but the same behaviour should be applicable to any uiview control I'd suppose, i.e. to fill up the remaining space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your constraints, but based on what's happening and the fact that you see **red** lines indicates something is not correct.

Here is a basic layout:

[image]

Which results in this:

[image]

As you can see, when the text is too long for the label, it gets **...** truncated, instead of pushing on into the button.

I set the button's Content Insets (to match your image):

[image]

And it's important that the button's Content Hugging and Compression Resistance is set as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The compression resistance prio fixed it!